# Setting template or templateUrl in Angular Directive based on user input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have simple directive like this :

```
app.directive('sample',function(){
 return{
           restrict:'E',
    template:'<a href="#">Hello sample</a>',
    templateUrl:''
 }
});
```

i want when user declare `templateUrl` in tag like this :

```
<sample template="some url"></sample>
```

use `templateUrl` but if nothing set use default template in directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`template` and `templateUrl` can be specified as functions taking two arguments - `tElement` and `tAttrs`.

An easy way is to move your default template and perform your logic in the `templateUrl` function:

```
app.directive("sample", [
  function() {

    var defaultTemplate = 'default.html';

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
        return tAttrs.template || defaultTemplate;
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/rrPicuzzb6YF4Z6yh3Rn?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `transclude`:

```
app.directive('sample',function(){
    return {
       restrict:'E',
       transclude: true,
       template:'<a href="#">Hello sample <div ng-transclude></div></a>
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<sample>
    <div ng-include="some url"></div>
</sample>
```